# Shopify Liquid Code for scalable image for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, shopify, shopify-liquid

Need some help with using Custom Liquid in Shopify. Basically I am using a custom liquid section to add an image. I know enough to get the image where I want, but the issue is when viewed on mobile, the image doesnt resize and flow off the screen.

I can do it with a video and get the results I am after, just need to do with video.

Below is the code I am putting in the custom liquid section for video and then also the code I am using for this image. **Basically I am just trying to get the image to scale like my video does.**
---Go easy on me, I dont know nada about this stuff--

**Code I use for video that gives the results I am after**

```
<style>
 
video { 
 
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 30%;
 
}
 
</style> 
 
<video autoplay loop playsinline muted> 
<source src="VIDEO LINK HERE">
</video>
```

**What I have tried for this image that I need to scale the way the video does**

```
<center><p>
    <a href="PAGE LINK HERE">
    <img src=IMAGE LINK HERE" alt="">
    </a>
</p></center
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for many, many years.

Comment: At the time of video css is appiled `width:100%`, and for image their no css, you need to add the CSS for image tag also.

Comment: Not considered about the video, it works as I need it to, but thank you. It was an example on how I want the image to scale. Not sure if my question makes sense.